# Making dc.js charts reactive in Meteor

Tags: meteor, charts, dc.js, crossfilter

I'm using [dc.js](https://github.com/dc-js/dc.js/blob/master/web/docs/api-latest.md) and [crossfilter](https://github.com/square/crossfilter/wiki/API-Reference) to create some charts in [Meteor](https://www.meteor.com). Everything is set, I have all the charts ready, but there is 1 question regarding making the charts reactive. I `subscribe` number of collections from `mongoDB` on client side in JavaScript files; here, I have to update the data that I pass to crossfilter every time the data in collections change.

Suppose, for each page on the app I'm subscribing to 8 different collections, each of the collections have about 30 data fields/columns. This data in every field keeps changing or updating for every 30 seconds or so. Now the question is, as the data changes charts in the page must be updated with new data and re-render all the charts.

I learned that there are a couple of methods in Meteor which makes the page reactive like `deps.autorun( )` and `tracker.autorun( )`. The problem is, what code should I put in the above functions to make my charts reactive?

PS: please comment back if you need any clarification, the question is already getting lengthy.

Comment: Shouldn't you just call dc.redrawAll() whenever you add data to the Crossfilter?

Comment: Right, `dc.redrawAll( )` might work. But the question is as I'm not manually adding the data to the collections. The charts must update automatically whenever there is any slightest of the change in the data. Like some value `total : 100` changes to `total : 200`. Note that only values are changing but they are not adding extra rows to the collection.

Comment: You can't change internal data in the Crossfilter, can you?

Comment: Yeah, so your best option is going to be to either remove the old record and add a new, updated one, or just push a delta (which will work as long as you are just doing sums and counts). Either way, you'll have to use crossfilter.add() when your data changes and after you do that you'll want to call dc.redrawAll().

Answer (score 1):

Say you have a 'dcChart' template and you are calling that template from your main page as

```
{{> dcChart data=dcChartData}}
```

helper for data as:

```
'dcChartData': function () {
    var data = SomeCollection.find(...);
    return data;
}
```

Your code should look something like this:

```
Template.dcChart.rendered = function () {
  var template = this;
  buildChart(template.data);

  template.autorun(function () {
     var templateData = Template.currentData();
     buildChart(templateData);
  });
}
```

In the autorun section you rerender the chart by passing the reactive data(records from the collection). So every time the collection is updated the chart will be rendered again).

Comment: Thanks for your answer... Actually, I have around 15-20 charts on a page and all these charts are rendered using a single template. Then about autorun section you mentioned, I have almost 10 collections data passed to 10 different crossfilters. Each collection has about 30 data fields and every field changes for every 30 secs. That is the complexity.